# A condition equivalent to $R$ being a direct summand

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

If $R\subset S$ are rings, then why is saying that $R$ is a summand of $S$ as an $R$-module the same as saying that there is an $R$-module homomorphism $S\to R$ that fixes all elements of $R$?

The first condition means that $S\simeq R\oplus R'$ as $R$-modules for some $R$-module $R'$. The only natural map is $R\oplus R'\to R, (r,r')\mapsto r$. But what confuses me is that $R$ isn't a submodule of $S$ now (though it is isomorphic to the submodule $R\oplus \{0\})$.The above map indeed fixes all elements of $R\oplus \{0\}$. But how to deal with the fact that $R\subset S$ is not true?

Also, how to prove the other direction?

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of “internal direct sum”? You seem to be viewing the direct sum only as an “external” direct sum; but one says that $R$ is a direct summand of $S$ when $R\subseteq S$ if there is a submodule $R’$ of $S$ such that $R\cap R’=\{0\}$ and $R+R’ = S$. In that case, it is not hard to verify that each element $s\in S$ can be written *uniquely* as $r+r’$ with $r\in R$ and $r’\in R’$, so that $S\cong R\oplus R’$ (the “external” direct sum made up of ordered pairs with coordinate-wise operations)

Comment: For the converse, verify that the kernel of the homomorphism is a complement to $R$ (i.e., it intersects $R$ trivially, and every element of $S$ can be written as a sum of an element of $R$ and an element of the kernel)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So if I view it as an internal direct sum, is the $R$-module homomorphism in question the inclusion map? In particular, are you talking about the inclusion map in the second comment?

Comment: What do you mean “the homomorphism in question”? The only one mentioned goes from $S$ to $R$, not form $R$ to $S$, so how could it be an inclusion?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry, I mistakenly thought that it was from $R$ to $S$. But then I still need to use external direct sums to define the homomorphism? What's the advantage of thinking about internal direct sums then?

Comment: The external and internal direct sums are isomorphic; they are interchangeable. But in one (the external) the underlying set is literally a set of pairs, whereas in the other (the internal) it need not be, allowing it to work more generally. No, you don’t need to “use” the external direct sum here, except as inspiration/guide. It should all happen inside of $S$.

Comment: Note that in the converse, you are assuming that you already have a map $f\colon S\to R$ that is a module homomorphisms and such that $f(r)=r$ for every $r\in R$. You don’t define the map there, you assume it exists.